# Active Model Driven Architecture (MDA) Tools

Tags: mda

Could you provide a list of active **MDA tools** like AndroMDA? Tools like *arcstyler* or *optimalj* seems to be discontinued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EMF](https://eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) (Eclipse Modeling Framework) provides various tools depending on your needs including ORM and BPM frameworks for object and business process models. EMF Forms supports creating GUI based on object model.